# How to filter propertly or how to explode specific string

Tags: php

Sorry to bother but I have tried now everything -.-

```
(INPUT STRING)
kronobergslan_Preem_AlmhultS_Esplanaden__diesel
```

this is the string, first value after _ is separate, second value after _ is separate, every other values except the last after __ is together as separate value.

so basically I want to make this:

```
(EXPECTED OUTPUT)
$a = kronobergslan
$b = Preem
$c = Almult S Esplanden
$d = diesel
```

Example 2:

```
(INPUT STRING)
kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoSodra_Vallviksvagen_352_51_Vaxjo__diesel
```

- 

```
(EXPECTED OUTPUT)
$a = kronobergslan
$b = Circle K
$c = Vaxjo Sodra Vallviksvagen 35251 Vaxjo
$d = diesel
```

I have tried everything.

```
public function filter($call){
        // kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoEvedalsvagen__diesel to Kronobergslan CircleK (Vaxjo Evedalsvagen)
        // kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__diesel to Kronobergslan Ingo (Vaxjo Smedjegatan 28 Morners vag)
        // return array
        $parts = explode("_", $call);
        $parts = array_map('ucfirst', $parts);
        // if part 2 and 3 is cirlek make one string
        if($parts[1] == "Circle"){
            $parts[1] = $parts[1] . " " . $parts[2];
            unset($parts[3]);
        }
        
        $parts[10] = ucfirst(substr($call, strpos($call, "__") + 2)); 

         //= $parts[count($parts) - 1];

        if ($parts[2] != "K"){
            $part = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$parts[2]);
            $parts[2] = implode(' ', $part);
            $parts[2] = $parts[2] . " " . $parts[3];
            unset($parts[3]);
        }else if ($parts[2] == "K"){
            $parts[2] = "test";
        }

        return $parts;
    }
```

Would be thankful if someone could explain how to approach this problem and how to solve it so I would learn from it and probably be able to solve it other times.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood well what you want, please comment here only the input string and expected result.

Comment: Input String: kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoSodra_Vallviksvagen_352_51_Vaxjo__diesel
Result: 
$a = kronobergslan
$b = Circle K
$c = Vaxjo Sodra Vallviksvagen 35251 Vaxjo
$d = diesel

Comment: How is the parser supposed to know whether `Circle_K_VaxjoSodra` should be parsed into `Circle K` and `VaxjoSodra` or `Circle` and `K VaxjoSodra`?

Comment: Split by _ if Cirkle_K then convert to Circle K etc

Answer (score 0):

You're presented with a few problems with your expected input strings.

```
#kronobergslan_Preem_AlmhultS_Esplanaden__diesel

$parts = explode('_', $call);

#Outputs:
#kronobergslan
#Preem
#AlmhultS
#Esplanaden
#[empty entry]
#diesel
```

I would suggest, replace every space with another custom boundary, that way in the example of `AlmhultS_Esplanaden` you can still separate the input string with a simple `explode` and not have it be confused in these instances. Once separated, you can replace the `_` with a `\s`.

I'm not sure why the last value has a double-underscore `__` but since it's there, you can still use `explode` and then just remove the 2nd last value in the returned array using the [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) method.

```
$parts = explode('_', $call);
$count = count($parts);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $parts[$i] = preg_replace('/','/\s/');
}
unset($parts[$count]-1);
```

As a side note, never use `"` unless you're concatenating a string. Always use `'` single quotes.